# Аналог функции ignore_row_on_dupkey_index в MSSQL(или ОРМ hibernate)

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

Возникла необходимость перейти с  Oracle  на  MSSQL. В  oracle  использовались голые запросы, и при переходе я решил сразу переехать на ОРМ. И такая проблема сейчас. есть такой запрос:

```
insert /*+ ignore_row_on_dupkey_index(avaya_cm_cdr, i_avaya_cm_cdr_nodub) */  into avaya_cm_cdr(acmcdr_id, cdrdate, cdrtime, secdur, condcode, attdconsole, codeused, outcrtid, codedial, dialednum, intrkcode, incrtid, callingnum, vdn, bcc, ppm, acctcode, authcode) values(seq_acmcdr_id.nextval, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

вот этот кусок `/*+ ignore_row_on_dupkey_index(avaya_cm_cdr, i_avaya_cm_cdr_nodub) */`

Как это реализовать в  MSSQL? Хотябы голым запросом атким же, но если кто знает то как в ОРМ сделать такое?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю как это в Oracle, похоже, что эту опцию можно указать непосредственно на запрос. В SqlServer есть опция `ignore_dup_key = on`, но она указывется при создании или пересоздании индекса:

```
create unique index IX_TableName_IndexName on TableName (KeyColumn1, KeyColumn2, ...)
    with (ignore_dup_key = on)
```

Либо

```
alter index IX_TableName_IndexName on TableName
    rebuild with (ignore_dup_key = on)
```